# Create multiple columns from a single column filtering criteria?

Tags: mysql, performance

thanks in advance for your time, what I need to achieve is generate multiple columns result from a single query, the thing is this:

I got a table were is storing the next:

```
id | user_id | revision
1       1      Approved
2       1      Rejected
3       1      Pending
4       1      Pending
5       1      Pending
```

What I need is to get the next result:

```
Total | User | Pending | Rejected | Approved
  5       1       3         1           1
```

I have tried using Group by like this:

```
SELECT count(id) Total, user_id User, revision FROM table1 GROUP BY user_id, revision
```

But the output is way to far from what I am spectating to get:

```
Total | User | revision
  3      1      Pending
  1      1      Rejected
  1      1      Approved
```

The idea is to get the proper object returned to avoid over cycling the server side code with unnecessary processes, so If the database can do the handling in one call this would be great.

I tried googling for hours and all I could get were a lot of results for 'single column from multiple rows' which is something I do not need, thanks for your help in advance.

The final result set with many users should look like this:

```
Total | User | Pending | Rejected | Approved
  5       1       3         1           1
  5       2       4         0           1
  5       7       2         3           0
```

**Updated:**
After more researching I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172282/sql-query-needed-to-get-result-in-two-columns-grouped-by-type-and-percentage-in

This is almost what I need after some editing I still can't get it to send it in solid numbers instead percentages, I lack the knowledge for working group cases, I will keep trying if any of you can help it is greatly appreciated.

**Solution**
Hey I managed to do this, it was easy, but my lack of knowledge was in the middle, I read the chapter Generating Summaries in MySQL Cookbook, this is where they explain that you can create count, sum and other methods inside your query to gain the proper values in those columns you define, so this is the query I ended up using:

```
SELECT user_id as userid, count(id) Total,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'pending', 1, NULL)) as pending,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'approved', 1, NULL)) as approved,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'rejected', 1, NULL)) as rejected
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id
```

This will fill those values by count only if criteria is met.

Comment: I just did it, but I can't answer my own question because my low leve of poster :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the chapter Generating Summaries in MySQL Cookbook, this is where they explain that you can create count, sum and other methods inside your query to gain the proper values in those columns you define, this is known as statistical queries and then this is the query I ended up using:

```
SELECT user_id as userid, count(id) Total,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'pending', 1, NULL)) as pending,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'approved', 1, NULL)) as approved,
COUNT(IF(revision = 'rejected', 1, NULL)) as rejected
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id
```

This will fill those values by count only if criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT  COUNT(ID) TOTAL ,
        USER_ID ,
        PENDING = ( SELECT  COUNT(REVISION) APPROVED
                    FROM    MYTABLE
                    WHERE   REVISION = 'pending'
                  ) ,
        REJECT = ( SELECT   COUNT(REVISION) APPROVED
                   FROM     MYTABLE
                   WHERE    REVISION = 'REJECT'
                 ) ,
        APPROVED = ( SELECT COUNT(REVISION) APPROVED
                     FROM   MYTABLE
                     WHERE  REVISION = 'APPROVED'
                   )
FROM    MYTABLE
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: Try to rewrite without CTEs. MySQL has not this feature.

Comment: YOU CAN TRY THIS NOW :

Comment: actually I already solved it yesterday, using statistical queries works perfectly to match and not overload the query iterations. Thanks for your idea.